# Import form design from Illustrator to Word

Tags: adobe-illustrator, microsoft-word, import

I  created a form document design for a company in Adobe Illustrator.

- How can I export it to Word?
- How can I make it possible to type in date, right where I drew lines for it?
- How can I make background image non-selectable so the user can type over it?

Comment: You really can not do this in a satisfactory way due to the way word works.

Comment: It's also possible to create forms in Word, or export to PDF as a fillable form.

Answer (score 1):

Word Doesn't really allow you to do that...
But you can try some tricks to get close to what you want like using text boxes so you can place them where you want people to write and drop some dummy text in it so they know where they should be writing.

For an image on the background non-selectable I usually do this:

Make an image (say A4 / the size your document will be).
Export it as a Jpeg 
In word use the **Insert** menu and choose **header** [blank]
Drop your jpeg inside the header section.

After this  you need to format the position of the image so you can move it freely as your layout requires.

Go to **Picture Format** and follow these instructions below for positioning options

[image: 1]]

Choose **behind text**

[image: 2]]

position the image as you want and then close the header

[image: 3]]

After closing the header the image will dim down its opacity.
**Just make sure you don't forget that when you print a document the opacity will be 100%.** Word just does that so you know that object is not on edit mode.

Like I said, its not ideal and technically anyone can edit the background of the document but it is not very often that people go and edit the header of documents and I usually ask them not to open header or footer when I have to deal with these kind of documents.